# Tkinter display the file path and then open text file on another button

Tags: python, button, text, tkinter, filepath

I am a beginner in creating GUI using tkinter so I decided to start by making a notepad-like application. Now, I want to display the filepath of my selected text file and then insert its contents to another Entry box. My problem here is that I cannot get the content for the other function of the OPEN button. I hope to get lesson/answer here, thanks!

```
def browsefunc():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    content = infile.read()
    pathadd = os.path.dirname(filename)+filename

    pathlabel.delete(0, END)
    pathlabel.insert(0, pathadd)

    return content


browsebutton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=browsefunc)
browsebutton.pack()
browsebutton.grid(row=0)

pathlabel = Entry(root, textvariable=pathadd,width=90,)
pathlabel.pack()
pathlabel.grid(row=1)

def openfunc():
   global content
   data = content
   textFile.delete(0, END)
   textFile.insert(0,data)

openbutton = Button(root, text="Open Now",command=openfunc)
openbutton.pack()
openbutton.grid(row=2)

scrollText = Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical')
textFile = Text(root, bg='white', width=90, height=29, relief='groove', 
                           wrap='word')
textFile.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
scrollText.config (command=textFile.yview)
scrollText.grid(column=1, row=3,sticky='NS',padx=(1,5),pady=(17,1))
textFile.grid(row=3)
textFile.config(state='disabled')
scrollText.config(command=textFile.yview)
```

Comment: from which module did you import `askopenfilename`? I would suggest that you should close your file after reading it, but I can't try it out. By the way, it's way better to put your instances of `Tkinter`-widgets in a class ;)

Comment: I have this code above the def browsefunc():

    import Tkinter as tk
    import os
    from Tkinter import *
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
    from Tkinter import END
    
    root = Tk()

Comment: I just want a simple notepad-like GUI where I want to display the filepath then open its contents....My problem is that I cannot get the content of the textfile where it was a variable from the browsefunc()

Comment: Did you try to insert `global content` before `content = infile.read()` in `browsefunc`?

Comment: I tried putting `global content` in the `browsefunc()` but only got a `TclError: bad text index "0" `